# Vaadin Maven Build Failure

Tags: maven, vaadin7

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
                        <arg>1400000</arg>
                    </args>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://127.0.0.1:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration></configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Gives Below error while executing build:

```
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[

Using maven 3 , vaadin 7.This compilation is failing on Unix system on windows it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by increasing space allocated.